# Playing Ultima VI from floppy disks?

Tags: ultima-6

I have an old IBM 286 computer without a hard drive and I'd like to play *Ultima VI* on it using 3.5" 1.44MB floppies. I own a legal copy via the *Ultima Collection*, but it just has a single directory with all of the floppy contents (and some extra files) jumbled together. **How can I find out which files to put on which disks?**

I know the number and names of the disks from [the manual](http://www.abandonia.com/files/extras/23602_game_extra_1.pdf), but not the contents:

> ***If You Use High Density Floppy Disks***
>
> *Ultima VI* comes on low density, 360K disks. If you have a higher density 5 1/4" or 3.5" drive and a low density floppy drive, you can
>   copy two original *Ultima VI* disks onto each of your high-density
>   disks. This will allow you to play the game with fewer diskswaps.
>   Here's the most efficient combination of disks: PROGRAM/INTRO, GAME/
>   ENDGAME, MAP/PLAYER, POPULACE A/POPULACE B.

Comment: This forum thread seems to list the disk contents: http://www.vcfed.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-12168.html

Comment: Yay, that worked! Well, sort of. Alas, the Ultima Collection includes a different executable than the original floppies and it does not work on a 286.